# Change colour of Scroll View Indicator for Android in Appcelerator

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

I have a scroll view defined in the XML file for a controller:

```
<ScrollView id="searchResultsContainer"/>
```

In the TSS, I show the scrollbar indicator to true:

```
"#searchResultsContainer":{
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    layout: "vertical",
    width: "100%",
    top: "65dp",
    height: "400dp",
    showVerticalScrollIndicator: "true"
}
```

How do I set the colour of the scroll bar? It is currently grey and not very visible on a grey background.

Answer (score 0):

[You can edit these properties](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:scrollbarThumbHorizontal), create a new custom theme, you can set them to a 9 patch image for example.